# nested dict in a list with custom string

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

Below is my list, how can i add a string called "Parent Name" so that all "Name" and their "values" are nested under "Parent name" like below

```
data_1 = [{'Name': 'value 1'},
{'Name': 'value 2'},
{'Name': 'value 3'}]
```

how to get below:

```
 [{'Parent Name':{ 'Name': 'value 1', 'Name': 'value 2', 'Name': 'value 3'}]
```

Comment: It's not possible to have several identical keys in a dict.

Comment: @Corralien While technically true, it is none the less possible to construct a simple object that would effectively allow for multiple semi-duplicate keys. I'm guessing you know that, but just noting it here for other future visitors. Of course, if we did such a thing it would be of highly dubious value.

Comment: @Kumar Are you sure that is the result you seek?  It would be very uncommon to want such a result.  Any chance you want more like `{"Parent Name": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]}` or perhaps `{"Parent Name": [("name", "value 1"), ("name", "value 2"), ("name", "value 3")]}`?

Comment: @jonSG, the data i get from my command has same multiple keys but different values, how to achieve {"Parent Name": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]}??

Comment: Try: `{"Parent Name" : [x["Name"] for x in data_1]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_1 = [{'Name': 'value 1'},
{'Name': 'value 2'},
{'Name': 'value 3'}]
```

In your question you said you need output like:

```
[{'Parent Name':{ 'Name': 'value 1', 'Name': 'value 2', 'Name': 'value 3'}]
```

However, you cannot get this exact output as `'Name'` will override with the latest value.

If you run :

```
{ 'Name': 'value 1', 'Name': 'value 2', 'Name': 'value 3'}
```

you will get:

```
{'Name': 'value 3'}
```

In the comments, you are saying you need :

```
{"Parent Name": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]}
```

you can get this by (as @JonSG commented)

```
{"Parent Name" : [x['Name'] for x in data_1]}

#output
{"Parent Name": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]}
```

Comment: it is *technically* possible to get that output if we allow object instances to be keys.